# how to log to StringIO from a multiprocessing Process

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, stringio

I just can't get a StreamHandler working with StringIO to accept logging from a Process.  The strange thing is that a stream to stdout works just fine.

This is my code:

```py
from time import sleep
import logging
import multiprocessing
from io import StringIO


logBuffer = StringIO()
#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,stream=logBuffer)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This will get logged')


def main():
    for i in range(10):
        logging.debug('i=%i' % i)
        print(i)
        sleep(0.5)

# start process
proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=main )
proc.start()
proc.join()

print(logBuffer.getvalue())
sleep(3)
```

using 
`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` prints everything to stdout:

```
DEBUG:root:This will get logged
DEBUG:root:i=0
0
DEBUG:root:i=1
1
DEBUG:root:i=2
2
DEBUG:root:i=3
3
DEBUG:root:i=4
4
DEBUG:root:i=5
5
DEBUG:root:i=6
6
DEBUG:root:i=7
7
DEBUG:root:i=8
8
DEBUG:root:i=9
9
```

while trying to capture with StringIO with `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,stream=logBuffer)` captures only current **main** output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
DEBUG:root:This will get logged
```

Can anybody help?  Other solutions for passing real-time output from a Process to the parent process are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer in the [logging-cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes), using a QueueHandler, so I'll answer my own question (RTFM) ;-).

However an easier solution seems to be switching to Threading and passing a logger instance to the trhead function.